# Laravel Multiple wildcards routing

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-blade

I have updated my routes restfully as below;

```
Route::resource('lists', 'UserlistsController');
Route::resource('lists.items', 'UseritemsController');
```

I can see my routes in PHP Artisan Routes below (Broken up for easier reading);

```
GET|HEAD lists/{lists}/items/{items}/edit    |
lists.items.edit     |
UseritemsController@edit
```

I want to be able to get to these routes but am unsure what I need to pass and how.

For example on a page displaying the users items *WITHIN a list* for example the URL may be *domain.com/lists/2* I want to click a button on the item to destroy or edit it.

In my view I have the following code when going through a foreach loop...

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('lists.items.edit', $userlist->id, $useritem->id) }}">
```

Clicking this route simply takes me to *domain.com/lists/2/items//edit* and the code breaks. How can I get my items to redirect properly to the correct route.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me, I forgot about putting them in an array;

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('lists.items.edit', $userlist->id, $useritem->id) }}">
```

SHOULD BE

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('lists.items.edit', array($userlist->id, $useritem->id)) }}">
```